# cannot debug in python (pycharm)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, debugging, pycharm

I have a strange problem with debugging python in pycharm (2017). I can debug an old code of the same project but I cannot debug the current project. Looks like something I wrote in the code prevented the debugger to work (I did not even known it's possible).

When I try to debug in the current project, the debugger stops at the breakpoint but I cannot see the values of the variables in the variables window (if I click on a variable to see its content it says 'Collecting data' and after a while it says in red 'Unable to display children:Timeout waiting for response'. and when I click on the 'next' button, the breakpoint line disappears (instead of moving to the next line).

Anyone knows what kind of changes in code can cause this problem (maybe an import that cannot work with debugger etc). I could not identify the problem since there are too many differences between the two versions of the code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: check whether this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537942/why-python-debugger-always-get-this-timeout-waiting-for-response-on-113-when-usi

Comment: No it doesn't. I didn't use any of the methods he mentioned in the reply.

Comment: I've seen that sort of thing before when I was dealing with multi-threaded projects in older version of python... but that has been fixed for a while.

Comment: I'm not using any threads in my code :(. I've been searching my code all over and can't figure it out :(. It's really driving me crazy.

Comment: What version of Python are you using, and what version of Pycharm are you using?