# timeout waiting for response on 115

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, python-requests, microservices

```
training_response = requests.post("https://13.77.109.108:5000/initiateFailure",
                                   data=open('failure_labels.json', 'rb'),
                                   verify=False,headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

The above code is a flask server sending request to a virtual machine with another flask instance as a part of microservice based architecture. It returns a 200 response and does not return its execution and gets hung up in this line. 
With the above code I am training a machine learning model & hence it takes time to return me with a network response object. 
I also using a pycharm debugger to evaluate this expression which gave me the below error

```
timeout waiting for response on 115
```

Has anyone faced this issue? Is it a request timeout issue and if yes how do I increase the timeout time?

Environment details:
Ubuntu 18.04LTS
default python3.6.9
using virtualenv

Comment: Hi, please look at this quastion: [why python debugger always get this timeout waiting for response on 113](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537942/why-python-debugger-always-get-this-timeout-waiting-for-response-on-113-when-usi)

Comment: Ok if this is a debugger issue then when I run using command line why is the service still unable to get any response?